# Find all li elements that have ul in them

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list below, I want to add content after `li` elements what have `ul` elements in them. How can I do that with CSS or jQuery?

```
<ul>
    <li> item 1 </li>
    <li> item 2 
        <ul>
            <li> item 2.1 </li>
            <li> item 2.2 </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `i want to add a content after li elements` Can you update your question with more info on what content you want to add and is it for every `li`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Append the element by selecting the li with direct ul then go back to its parent

```js
$('ul > li > ul').parent().append('<span>span</span>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li> item 1 </li>
   <li> item 2 
       <ul>
         <li> item 2.1 </li>
         <li> item 2.2 </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li> item 3 </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li > ul').each(function(){
        $(this).before('<span style="color:red">[I Have Content]</span>');
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<ul>
   <li> item 1 </li>
   <li> item 2 
       <ul>
         <li> item 2.1 </li>
         <li> item 2.2 </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li> item 3 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your content into a span within li and try to attach some content to it after using css as explained below

```css
ul>li span::after{
content:' hello';
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li> <span>item 1</span> </li>
   <li> <span>item 2</span>
       <ul>
         <li> <span>item 2.1</span> </li>
         <li> <span>item 2.2</span> </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li> <span>item 3</span> </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers the `:has` pseudoselector for this, which CSS unfortunately does *not* have:

```js
$('ul > li:has(li)').append('<span>span</span>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li> item 1 </li>
   <li> item 2 
       <ul>
         <li> item 2.1 </li>
         <li> item 2.2 </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li> item 3 </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this css:

```
li>ul>li:after{
content: "what you want to add";
}
```

It will only select the ul>li that inside li.

Comment: Always give some explanation about your answer. Otherwise it will treat as a low quality post.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: its not just a low quality post, it answers anything else than OP wants.